# unable to establish communication using grabserial

Tags: serial-console

I have use teraterm in past and it works fine. 
I can see log messages coming from my board.
Ultimately I reach the login prompt where I enter my login and password for OS running on my board.

Now I am trying to do the same using [grabserial](http://elinux.org/Grabserial). But here I reach the login prompt, but after that nothing happens. The password option never comes. And even if I enter password, nothing happens (but my password that I am typing is visible).

```
grabserial -v -d "/dev/ttyUSB0" -b 115200 -w 8 -p N -s 1 -e 30 -t -m "Starting kernel.*"
```

Why it is happening.

Also I am running the grabserail as a root, and if i don't do this I get permission related error.

Why this is happening?

**Additionally** I found that in teraterm when I used to see the following message (actually log message from my board):

```
Hit any key to stop autoboot
```

Then it counts upto 5 seconds for the user to input a key.

It really worked. I was able to stop this autoboot by pressing a key.

But in case of grabserial when I see this message and type any key , the character appears on the console, but nothing happens, ultimately it boot in auto after 5 seconds.

Both these issues (password option not coming and the above one), indicates that the communication is perhaps only in one direction. My input is not going to the board via grabserial. But it was going through Teraterm when I was using it.

Any guess why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0):

By reading the [documentation for grab serial](http://elinux.org/Grabserial)

You will find that it, does not read the keyboard.

> Normally, the program runs in an infinite loop, reading from the
>   serial port and writing to standard out until it is interrupted by the
>   user (usually by typing control-C). However, you can tell the program
>   to stop after a certain amount of time. This is useful for including
>   the script in automated test scenarios.